# I have a brother MFC-J480DW that I can not get the scanner to hookup with any of the scanner programs

Tags: scanner

Here is the message I get: **Error opening device: opening device 'brother4:bus2;dev5': Invalid argument**...I have no idea where to change this, I have looked but can not find it, also if I did find it I have no idea what to change it to....Help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Download the tool: http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006893/linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1.gz

The tool will be downloaded into the default "Download" directory, e.g. /home/UserName/Download

Open a terminal window:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Go to the directory you downloaded the file to in the last step:

```
cd /home/UserName/Download
```

Enter this command to extract the downloaded file:

```
gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1.gz
```

Get superuser authorization with the sudo command:

```
exec sudo -i
```

Run the tool:

```
cd /home/UserName/Download
bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1 MFC-J480DW
```

The driver installation will start. Follow the installation screen directions.

When you see the message "Will you specify the DeviceURI ?",

```
For USB Users: Choose N(No)
For Network Users: Choose Y(Yes) and DeviceURI.
```

The install process may take some time. Please wait until it is complete.

Comment: I have done all of that...It is setup according to all those directions.

Comment: Try run the scanner programs with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Annoyingly, my system required elevated privileges for the scanner to be detected.

From your error message I assume you're using simple-scan. If you have already installed all drivers, and if you selected the correct scanner from within the simple-scan application, then the following will possibly resolve your problem:
`gksudo simple-scan`

If you cannot for whatever reason install gksudo, regular sudo should suffice.

If you are still experiencing problems, they have an additional page with prerequisite stuff that may help you [here](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/before.html?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj480dw_us_eu_as&redirect=on).

For Ubuntu, it boils down to this:

```
sudo aa-complain cupsd
sudo mkdir /usr/share/cups/model
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/cupsys /etc/init.d/lpd
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/cups /etc/init.d/lpd
sudo mkdir /var/spool/lpd
sudo apt-get install csh tcsh
sudo apt-get install sane-utils
sudo aa-complain cupsd
sudo mkdir /usr/share/cups/model
```

Hope that helps.